# Optimized way of accessing elements from n-dimensional array using multiple indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I come from `R` background so pardon my ignorance if it's way too basic. I am wondering if there is a better way to access elements from a N-Dimensional array given multiple indices inb one go instead of looping over the indices list? Below is the reprducable code for `input` and `output`

```
#  TestData
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
test_input = np.random.randint(1000, size=144).reshape(1,12, 12,1)
indices = [np.array([[ 0,  1, 55,  0], 
                     [ 0,  5, 74,  0],
                     [ 0,  8, 55,  0],
                     [ 0, 14, 76,  0]])]
```

Output is a list or tuple of values present in those indices

I am trying something like `test_input[indices]` and obviously it won't work.

Comment: I suggest making you example smaller, use only 3 dimensions, make the matrix have only 10 values instead of 1000 and then post the actual output numbers you want. Also in python you typically name your variables like `test_input`. Also you should `input numpy as np` and then replace all the `numpy` usages in your code with `np`, it is the standard way to use numpy.

Comment: Show us what you want with a small example, such as `data=np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)`

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing is the documentation for numpy indexing with lists.  You need to provide a separate list or array for each dimension.  `data[list1,  list2, list3]`.  Or in the case of an array of indices, `data[idx[:,0], idx[:,1], etc]`.

Comment: I did go through that. I was wondering if I can pass the entire list of indices in one go rather than seperating by a `,`. Thanks for the suggestions though

Comment: Probably `data[tuple(idx.T)]`.

Comment: `container[idx1,idx2,idx3]` is the same as `container.__getitem__((idx1,idx2,idx3))`, one could emphasize that by writing `container[(idx1,idx2,ix3)]`. So, to keep your indices together make a tuple: `tuple(idx.T)` (it must be a tuple, not list nor array nor generator).

Comment: Would any of you mind posting the comment as an answer, I'll go ahead and accept.